# Magento order/checkout attribute

Tags: magento

I would like to create a custom attribute for magento which will be setup in some cases on checkout, so basiclly some special products will create flag attribute, so I can see on backend somebody have bought this products, I'm trying like this to create this attribute:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute("order", "used_special", array("type"=>"int"));
$setup->addAttribute("quote", "used_special", array("type"=>"int"));

$installer->endSetup();
```

in checkout I would like to setup this attribute, and from order on backed read it

but I'm getting error - Wrong entity ID

Anybody have idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run setup file and add custom column in sales_flat_order and sales_flat_quote tables,

eg.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_quote
  ADD COLUMN `restaurant_id` int(11) NULL default ''

");

$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order
  ADD COLUMN `restaurant_id` int(11) NULL default ''



");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Hope this helps!